# How can I get the external sd card of a phone? Android

Tags: java, android, file

I am working on a file manager for android and it is just for training purpose. I am having issues trying to get the external sd card of my phone. I tried many of the solutions on here, but none of them allow for this to happen. How can I do this?  I have a file adapater set up that takes file objects and lists them in a listView. TO get the internal sd card, I used the `Enviorment.getExternalStorage()` method, but that only works for phones with an sd card built in. I know that the path to the sd card is different for every manufacturer, but how can I accomplish this? What I am trying to ask is that is it

Comment: I didnt userstand this line: `I used the Enviorment.getExternalStorage() method, but that only works for phones with an sd card built in.`. Built in SD card ? Isn't SD card an external memory which you insert to your phone? If yes then on those devices where SD card is not present, how can you access it? I'm sorry if I misuderstood your question.

Comment: The docs spell it out pretty clearly: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal

Comment: The path to most data storage is actually quite consistent across manufacturers, though some may have more or none external cards.